# Open the oldest instance of an activity from stack and clear everything above it. Can it be managed using some flags with intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-navigation

Suppose I have a flow like.

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> Activity D -> Activity B (new instance) -> Activity C (new Instance)

Now, if I want to open activity B from here but rather than opening the last instance which I can get by supplying the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. I want to open the oldest instance. Can I do this using flags?

Or is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

use  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

This flag works similar to “launchMode = singleTask”.